# Getting error code 324 "Not valid video" when using codebird

Tags: php, twitter, codebird

I'm using the latest version of Codebird to tweet from my site. I'm trying to add the ability to tweet videos, the code successfully tweets images.

I can't find anything additional on the web. Here is the code:

```
\Codebird\Codebird::setConsumerKey(xxxx, xxxx);
$cb = \Codebird\Codebird::getInstance();
$cb->setToken(xxxx, xxxx);

$video = /path/to/file.mp4
$params = [
    'status' => mb_substr('the tweet text', 0, 280),
    'media_ids' => twitterUpdloadLargeFile($cb, $video)
];
$reply = $cb->statuses_update($params); // code 324 'not valid video'


function twitterUpdloadLargeFile($cb, $video) {
    $size_bytes = filesize($video); // test video 2.5MB
    $mime = mime_content_type($video);
    $fp  = fopen($video, 'r');

    $reply = $cb->media_upload([
      'command'     => 'INIT',
      'media_type'  => $mime,
      'media_category' => 'tweet_video',
      'check_progress' => true,
      'total_bytes' => $size_bytes,
    ]);
    $media_id = $reply->media_id_string;
    $segment_id = 0;
    while (! feof($fp)) {
      $chunk = fread($fp, 524288); // 512KB per chunk
      $reply = $cb->media_upload([
        'command'       => 'APPEND',
        'media_id'      => $media_id,
        'segment_index' => $segment_id,
        'media'         => $chunk
      ]);
       $segment_id++;
     }
    fclose($fp);

    $reply = $cb->media_upload([
      'command'       => 'FINALIZE',
      'media_id'      => $media_id,
      'media_category' => 'tweet_video',
    ]);
   return $reply->media_id_string;
}
```

The above code results in code 324 and the message "Not valid video", and nothing shows up on Twitter.

The INIT upload gives status 202.
Each APPEND gives status 204.
The 'FINALIZE' upload gives status 200.

Comment: What format is the video? What happens if you try to upload it via the web? Twitter has very strict format requirements https://help.twitter.com/en/using-twitter/twitter-videos

Comment: Same video (.mp4) via the twitter website goes through and posts normally. No issues.

Comment: after FINALIZE, you will need to check the status (using STATUS) to confirm that the media has finished processing.

Comment: Thank you Andy Piper!

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Andy Piper, I needed to add a status check for the video upload before using the media_id.

**Solution:**

```
\Codebird\Codebird::setConsumerKey(xxxx, xxxx);
$cb = \Codebird\Codebird::getInstance();
$cb->setToken(xxxx, xxxx);

$video = /path/to/file.mp4
$params = [
    'status' => mb_substr('the tweet text', 0, 280),
    'media_ids' => twitterUpdloadLargeFile($cb, $video)
];
$reply = $cb->statuses_update($params); // code 324 'not valid video'


function twitterUpdloadLargeFile($cb, $video) {
    $size_bytes = filesize($video); // test video 2.5MB
    $mime = mime_content_type($video);
    $fp  = fopen($video, 'r');

    $reply = $cb->media_upload([
      'command'     => 'INIT',
      'media_type'  => $mime,
      'media_category' => 'tweet_video',
      'check_progress' => true,
      'total_bytes' => $size_bytes,
    ]);
    $media_id = $reply->media_id_string;
    $segment_id = 0;
    while (! feof($fp)) {
      $chunk = fread($fp, 524288); // 512KB per chunk
      $reply = $cb->media_upload([
        'command'       => 'APPEND',
        'media_id'      => $media_id,
        'segment_index' => $segment_id,
        'media'         => $chunk
      ]);
       $segment_id++;
     }
    fclose($fp);

    $reply = $cb->media_upload([
      'command'       => 'FINALIZE',
      'media_id'      => $media_id,
      'media_category' => 'tweet_video',
    ]);

    $notDone = true;
    while($notDone) {
        $reply = $cb->media_upload([
          'command'       => 'STATUS',
          'media_id'      => $media_id,
        ]);
        if (!empty($reply->processing_info->check_after_secs)) {
            sleep($reply->processing_info->check_after_secs);
        } else {
            $notDone = false;
        }
    }
   return $reply->media_id_string;
}
```

Now it works correctly.